# Python - Take Folder of images as input for Face Recognition

Tags: python

If I have a folder with multiple images, all images of people, and I want the software to look at each face and store it in memory to then search for, is this possible?

At the moment I am asking the user to select a image as a source (face to look for in other folder)

However this limits functionality if it can only search for one person.

Here's a snippet:

```
#Ask user for file name
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

#Add known images 
image_of_person = face_recognition.load_image_file(filename)
person_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_person)[0]
```

The code takes the image the user selects, then adds the encoding of  the face.

**Is it possible to have the code search the entire folder for faces, then search for them all?**

Source Folder:

1. Person 1
2. Person 2
3. Person 3

Can I then use **all three** faces as input and search another folder for all faces? Rather than one specified persons image?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/) article on pyimagesearch.

As shown there, you can either create a pickle file to save list of images and encodings, use a database(like SQL) to store those, or just keep them in a list, depending on your application.